# Angular Jasmine - Mocking HttpClient ArrayBuffer Response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-httpclient, arraybuffer

I am writing Jasmine unit tests for old Angular code that I'm reluctant to change. Many of the calls to HttpClient.get overload it with an options object cast as `any`, and as a result, the compiler has it returning an Observable<ArrayBuffer>. Meanwhile, the component code is handling a call like this the same way it would handle an Observable<Object>.

```typescript
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({...})
export class ApiService {
    options: any;
    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
        let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
            .set('Cache-control', 'no-store')
            .set('Expires', '0')
            .set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        this.options = {
            headers: httpHeaders
        };
    }
    public getUser(userId) {
        return this.httpClient.get("https://service.com/getUser/" + userId, this.options); // compiler shows returning Observable<ArrayBuffer>
    }
}

// component code
@Component({...})
export class UserComponent {
    userName: string = "";
    constructor(private serv: ApiService) {}
    loadUser() {
        this.serv.getUser(this.userId).subscribe(result => {
            console.log("getUser", result);
            this.userName = result.userName; // directly accessing fields as if result were an Object
        });
    }
```

What I'm having trouble with is mocking the ArrayBuffer response to pass through a spy object in the spec file. I'm using `Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({...` to mock a response of the correct type, but the mock service returns the Buffer object full of integers and I can't convert that inside the component code.

```typescript
describe("component") {
    let component: UserComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;
    let fakeServ: jasmine.SpyObj<ApiService>;
    beforeEach(() => {
        fakeServ = jasmine.createSpyObj<ApiService>("ApiService", ["getUser"]);
        fakeServ.getUser.and.returnValue(of(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ // getUser returns Observable<Buffer>, compiler is OK
            "userName": "TESTUSER"
        }))));
        
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UserComponent],
            providers: [
            { provide: ApiService, useFactory: () => fakeServ },
        }).compileComponents();
        
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    it("should load user", () => {
        component.loadUser("TESTID");
        expect(component.userName).toBe("TESTUSER") // fails
    });
}
```

Console:

```
LOG: 'getUser', Buffer{0: 123, 1: 34, 2: 117, 3: 115, 4: 101, 5: 114, 6: 78, 7: 97, 8: 109, 9: 101, 10: 34, 11: 58, 12: 34, 13: 84, 14: 69, 15: 83, 16: 84, 17: 85, 18: 83, 19: 69, 20: 82, 21: 34, 22: 125}
```

Is there a way I can correctly pass an ArrayBuffer containing the actual response to the spy object?

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpClient.get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) has 15 overloads and `Observable<ArrayBuffer>` is just #1 of them.

In your case, the mock should return the desired object, likewise the real `HttpClient` would read and parse `ArrayBuffer` (overlodas #14 and #15).

Simply change it to:

```js
  fakeServ.getUser.and.returnValue(of({
    "userName": "TESTUSER"
  }));
```